# On Elementary Particles

Tags: terminology, antimatter, elementary-particles

The mass of positron and electron are same. Also their charges are equal in magnitude but opposite in nature. Then why positron is not called one of the elementary particles? Is this only because it was discovered after electron?

Comment: *"Then why positron is not called one of the elementary particles?"* [It is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron).

Comment: positron is an elementary particle

Comment: the positron is also significantly rarer (at least locally) compared to the electron. Only one of them would necessarily be on a list of "elementary particles" but also the list would include the antiparticles of the named ones... the positron *is* the antiparticle of the electron

Answer (score 2):

Positron **IS** an elementary particle, the anti-particle to the electron as you already know. But we do not get a "free positron" as a "free electron". They are usually generated through pair-production and get annihilated fast, or through radioactive decay (beta-decay) in weak interactions or in particle accelerators, and are present in cosmic rays too.

A positron is definitely as elementary as an electron but a lot rarer than electron; May be that's why people get the wrong idea that is is not elementary.

Answer (score 1):

Positron is as "elementary" as the electron, in the current theory. Period.

I took the word "elementary" in quote marks because if you hit a charged particle, it gets "broken apart" into the following pieces: the same charge and lots of neutral photons. It looks like the "target" is not that "elementary", but has "internal degrees of freedom", and sometimes it is called an "infra-particle".